# What is difference between two type of route on laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

What is/are the difference between the following route on laravel?

```
Route::resource('posts', 'Admin\PostsController');
Route::resource('posts', Admin\PostsController::class);
```

when should i use and which one should i use?

Thanks.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rules.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are completely different things.

'PostsController' is the string 'PostsController'

`Admin\PostsController::class` is most likely the string 'App\Http\Controllers\Admin\PostsController'

If you use the second one it will end up looking for `App\Http\Controllers\App\Http\Controllers\Admin\PostsController` as Laravel is already assuming the namespace for the controllers to be `App\Http\Controllers` based on what is set in your `RouteServiceProvider`.

When you use just 'PostsController' Laravel ends up with `App\Http\Controllers\PostsController`.

This is how its setup by default. (assuming you have no groups that are adjusting the namespace used)

Answer (score 0):

The difference between the two is that the first is going to look for a Controller within the same scope as the file in which you are specifying your routes. The second will look for a controller called `PostsController` iin the `Admin` namespace.

If these locations are one and the same, there will be no difference between the two routes.

In answer to the second part of the question, which one you choose to use is really up to you. I personally make use of route groups to handle my namespacing (among other things) like so:

```
Route::group([
    'namespace'  => 'Admin',
], function () {
    Route::resource('posts', 'PostsController');
}
```